# Rails. Switch roles of a single user to buyer/seller like in fiverr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan, rolify

I am developing a web application in rails that needs a single user to have two roles and he just switches between the two by a single click like that of Fiverr. I just want to know the best approaches and gems that do so. I have gone through 'rolify' and 'cancancan' but haven't figure out how to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving 'Rolify' and 'Cancancan' another shot. Because after defining the permissions in the `Ability` file, you can then just check if the current user has the permission with something like `can?(:read, ModelName)` in the view. In other areas you can check for the role with `user.has_role?(:admin)` or w/e you want to name them.

If you just can't get them to work, you could use an enum to create/check the role.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: %i[admin manager user]
end
```

And then you could check for the proper enum to view something, ie: `user.admin?`

You could also change the 'role' fairly easily by creating a controller action for that and just call `user.admin!` or whatever enum role you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I highly appreciate your help. But I am still not clear that how would I switch the role? Like if an admin is logged in and say it has all the rights. And there is a button that says "Switch to Manager", then the same user switches to manager role and some of the rights are taken back from him and vice-versa. Any help?

Comment: Ya with the enum you'd have more code to do checks all over to see if the user has the proper enum role. With the two gems, you can check for the permission as I've described, also you can limit what the user can acess with `#current_ability`(method provided by cancancan). Also with the `load_and_authorize_resource` method, it will perform the checks for permissions defined in the `Ability.rb`

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Let me try it.